# Casting Shadows on object through a transparent-like object

Tags: transparency, shadows

I am having some trouble trying to receive some shadows that are being casted by various other objects. I’ve placed a transparent like object between the other object that I want to receive shadows and the Objects that I want to cast the shadows. Not sure if my transparency settings are correct or if I should be thinking about some render properties that need to be modified. [here is a sample video](https://vimeo.com/832453927)
[with the mirror like object (a plane)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORHieElXmTOh40EdESLLoxxNPoZmcZxy/view?usp=drivesdk)
[without the mirror like object](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iNoznTB4LhCKeHy46JIOJWSLbLGo3jfr/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Hello, we can't see the video, maybe show some screenshots?

Comment: It is really hard to understand from your explanation what exactly is going on or going wrong, and as moonboots said we cannot see the video.

Comment: Just updated the post, so hopefully that provided more clarity. I also post some images. Let me know if you can’t see it. With the video, what do you see? I think a video would provide better clarity as well so I’d love to fix that if I could. @moonboots

Comment: I have a transparent like object in between some objects. I want to cast shadows through that transparent like object onto one of those two objects (think of a tree shadow between casted on different items inside of a room through a window).  I’ve updated my post so hopefully you better understand. Can you also let me know what you see from when you like the video link. I’d like to try to fix that. @GordonBrinkmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this setup for the glass material: Take a *Light Path* node, plug the *Is Shadow Ray* and *Diffuse Depth* output into a *Math* node set to *Maximum*. Use the result as mix factor in a *Mix Shader* node, there you plug the glass material in the first *Shader* input and a *Transparent BSDF* set to white in the second *Shader* input.

[image: glass shader]

Comment: This solved my issue! I had a gloss and glass mixed instead of a transparent node. That did the trick. I was wondering what the light path was doing since mixing the glass and transparent did the trick

Comment: @joA If you mix glass and transparent just with a single factor it is always transparent to some percentage - and here transparent does not mean see-through like glass (that's transmissive), but invisible. If you for example would only take a _Transparent BSDF_ set to white (= fully transparent), it would be invisible in the scene, which would not be like realistic glass. A windowpane is never completely invisible. It has reflections and depending on the angle it can even appear opaque. The _Light Path_ node helps reducing the scattering and darkening of glass where _Cycles_ struggles with.